# Only in Firefox got error "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have got error in Firefox **"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"**.In Chrome and Explorer all is fine. Maybe somebody can help. 
Here is the code:

```
function filterArray (data, elem, checkingData)
{
    let array = data.filter(function (item) { //FIREFOX points to this string 
        return (item[elem] !== checkingData);
    });
    return array;
}
```

Comment: There's no syntax error in the posted code, you probably have errors before that code, something that isn't properly closed

Comment: Which version of Firefox? Does it support `let`?  Does it work if you change it to `var`?

Comment: Want to add , that this problem is also in IE 10, but in IE11 all is fine.

Comment: `let` is definitely not supported by IE 10. http://caniuse.com/#feat=let

Comment: Firefox 40.0.03. And yes, it is working when i changed to var!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is outdated, and the `let` statement was not supported. I was getting the same error message in the console on an old version of Iceweasel but running the same code in a newer browser was error-free.

I also believed this might be an unclosed parentheses in one of the libraries I had included prior to the code but this was not the case, and anyway a separate JavaScript block would very unlikely produce an error because of unclosed brackets elsewhere, almost certainly not if the 'erroneous' code did not reference any previous block.
The short answer - browser not supporting the `let` statement.

Answer (score -2):

Change `let` to `var` and the error message will disappear.

Comment: Added this answer because otherwise the question still looks unanswered in search results.

Comment: That's hardly a satisfactory answer! You could simply have re-hashed someone else's comment if you wanted to reduce the count of unanswered questions on stackoverflow.